# Getting HTTP ERROR 404 after publishing ASP.NET application in Azure App Service with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an application in ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 that works fine when running in my local environnent using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.27703.2035).

On server side, the same application is displaying an HTTP ERROR 404.

[Screenshot on local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMAQS.png)

[Screenshot on server environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1m1x.png)

To publish the ASP.NET application, I am using the publish tool of Visual Studio and deploy everything on an App Service of Azure.

[Visual studio publish tool and project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqUij.png)

I tried to use FTP deployment instead of Web Deploy with no success. I also tried manualy with FileZilla with no success.

Is it possible that some sort of action is needed when publishing a project with custom libraries?

---

EDIT

What I know:

1. > **[dlls on server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zveFO.png)** I actualy have access to the wwwroot folder on server side: this mean I can access js, css, images, etc. But it seems that controllers, views and others folders don't exist on the server..
2. > **Libraries issus?** The problem appeared when I subdivided my project with the customs libraries CrmDatabaseManager, SysaidDatabaseManager and UserInterfaceLibrary.
3. > **[wwwroot inside wwwroot on server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IDMT.png)** A wwwroot folder include anoter wwwroot folder on the server; the first wwwroot folder contains all dlls, and inside it, there is another wwwroot folder containing css, js, images and etc, but no sign of controllers or views.
4. > **How I created the project** I created the project GPRH 
   >   [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhBCM.png) using ASP.NET Core 2.0 based on .NET Framework
5. [image: Publish configuration]
6. [image: Project properties]

Comment: Is it ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: On the project properties, the target framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: I am not sure but looking at your project structure it looks like the .NET Core App. Have you checked the GPRH project properties?

Comment: While publishing the project to Azure, click configure and ensure that target framework is .net core app

Comment: I uploaded a new picture in the post with how I used the wizard to create the project. In fact, I created the project as ASP.NET Core 2.0 then I choose .NET Framework as the target.

Using ASP.NET Core 2.0 based on ASP.NET Core caused some nugget package to be not compatible.

Actualy, the target framework for GPRH is .NET Framework 4.6.1 as shown on properties.

Comment: Can you also upload a screenshot of GRPH properties (Right click project in solution Explorer -> Properties->Application)? I am wondering how .NET Core targeted web app can be changed to .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Ok. I just had two pictures on the post.

Comment: Do you see any option of converting it back to .NET Core?

Comment: What happens when you do the web publish? Is it successful?

Comment: Monsin, I dont see any way to set the target to ASP.NET Core. I'm now trying whit a brand new project ASP.NET Core by adding files off my actual project.

Comment: When I publish the app, there is no error, it just open the web brower pointing to the site (as usual), but I get an HTTP ERROR 404. There is no error message. It seems that the only page I can access are those in wwwroot; so the static pages as css, iamges, js, etc.

Comment: It turns out that every pages referencing one of the custom libraries is giving an error 404, all the other pages are working properly. Is there any reason why libraries would not deploy correctly? Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that split the project with libraries did broke path references.

I was hard coding the path and there were no problems with that into the main project. When I splited the project with libraries, it caused an error 404.

To access a file in a libary, you need to do this manipulation first:

1. Right clic on the file > **Properties**
2. On **Build action**, choose **Always
   copy the file**

Then specifie the path this way on the library:

```
var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filePath = buildDir + @"\fileName.json";

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   // code here
}
```